# How to create Regex for search pattern with letter and number?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get all the folders inside a given path that match a pattern. The pattern I need is an `H` with a number that can go from `1` to `9`.

This is how I try to create a regular expression, but it crashes with an "Illegal pattern" exception:

```
Regex searchPattern = new Regex(@"(H\d +)\");
```

This is how I get the folders (paths):

```
List<string> folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Where(p => searchPattern.IsMatch(path)).ToList();
```

How can I create a proper regular expression that matches the letter `H` with a number?

Comment: Why not use `@"H[1-9]"`? An `H` with a digit. Could you please provide a couple of paths that should and should not match? Note that you cannot have a literal ``\`` at the end of the pattern, that is why you get an error.

Comment: Here's a good site you can play around with: http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: When doing it that way I get an ArgumentExeption: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: parsing "(H[1-9]" - Not enough )'s.

Comment: Why did you add `(`? There is no `(` in `@"H[1-9]"`.

Comment: Yes you're right. I also had a problem here p => searchPattern.IsMatch(path). I was using path instead of p. Thanks a lot

Comment: @EstebanVerbel:  I provided an answer with explanations.

Comment: To the person who downvoted the question, please explain the reason if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to create the Regular Expression but it crashes (illegal pattern)

The problem you have is caused by the literal `\` that is at the end of the pattern. The backslash is an escaping symbol in a regex pattern, and must be followed with some char.

A pattern that matches `H` is `H` and a pattern that matches a  digit from `1` to `9` is `[1-9]` (a positive character class). So, declare it as

```
var searchPattern = new Regex(@"H[1-9]");
```

Then, if you declare the variable as `p` in the lambda part, use `p` instead of `path` (the original directory you are searching for subfolders).

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide example input? If I run this:

```
var path = "H3";
var match = Regex.Match(path, "H[1-9]").Success;

if (match)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match found!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I get "Match found!" in console. Although, I don't know what your exact input is. My answer is based purely on: "The pattern I need is an H with a number that can go from 1 to 9.".

Answer (score 0):

The following code should suit your needs.
Please note your Lambda was using **path** instead of the argument **p**.

```
string path = "C:/my-path";
Regex searchPattern = new Regex(@"H\d");
List<string> folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Where(p => searchPattern.IsMatch(p)).ToList();
```